# Django filter for max difference between 2 columns

Tags: django

I have a table named `RoundTable` and it has 2 fields, the max number of seats and the number of currently occupied seats. I want to find the max difference between these two columns.

My model:

```
class RoundTable(models.Model):
    total_seats = models.SmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    occupied_seats = models.SmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    .... other fields
```

What would the query be like?

`RoundTable.objects.aggregate(?)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

RoundTable.objects
    .annotate(diff=F('total_seats')-F('occupied_seats'))
    .aggregate(Max('diff'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
from django.db.models import Max, F, ExpressionWrapper, IntegerField

RoundTable.objects.annotate(diff=ExpressionWrapper(
    F('total_seats') - F('occupied_seats'), output_field=IntegerField()
)).aggregate(max=Max('diff'))
```